# Generate requirements based on used imports

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

Is there any tool to generate `requirements` file based on actually used imports in your project, not only on output of pip freeze?

Rationale, as I see it:

it's nice and simple to generate `requirements` with `pip freeze`, when you start the project. Howether, when your project grows, you add some new dependecies, while other go away. It's already not very convinient to

`pip freeze -r old_requirements > new_requirements`

, as you already have some kind of tools installed into virtualenv, which are convinient, but are not needed for `requirements` (I'm talking about ipython or other such tools), so you have to correct `requirements` manually and clean them. Moreover, it's easy to forget to delete some library from `requirements`, when you project does not need it anymore, and a year later, you can't already remember, why it is there, and won't definetely delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/findimports

Answer (score 3):

I came across this https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs package, which does exactly, what I asked.

Answer (score -2):

If you're on a *ix (or Cygwin), perhaps:'

```
cat *.py | egrep '^import' | sed -e 's/^import //' -e 's/#.*$//' -e 's/ *$//' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: And what about the "from package import xxx" lines?